# Python: My regular expression doesn't match on some string cases

Tags: regex

I try to creating a regular expression and so far I made this code:

`(-?['0|1']{1}.[00000000e+00|       ]?){1}\s(-?['0|1']{1}.[00000000e+00|       ]?){1}`

My goal is to detect pattern that `({string pattern}{blank}{string pattern})`.

This is my string pattern:

```
'0'
'-0.'
'1.'
'-1.'
'1.00000000e+00'
'0.00000000e+00'
'-0.00000000e+00'
'-1.00000000e+00'
'0.    ' (The blanks can be at least 1 to 8 characters long.)
'-0.     ' (The blanks can be at least 1 to 8 characters long.)
'1.    ' (The blanks can be at least 1 to 8 characters long.)
'-1.   ' (The blanks can be at least 1 to 8 characters long.)
```

My code is mostly successful in test cases, but problems occur in some test cases.
(e.g. error occurred with '00000000e+00' or '       ')

Especially, it is too difficult for me because there can be at least 1 to 8 blank(`'   '`) characters.

This is my test case:

```
['0. 0.']
['0. 1.']
['1. 0.']
['1. 1.']
['-0. -0.']
['-0. 0.']
['0. -0.']
['1. -0.']
['1. -1.']
['-1. 1.']
['-1. -1.']
['-1.00000000e+00 0.']  # Fail
['0. -1.       ']  # Fail
['0. 0.       ']  # Fail
['-0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00']  # Fail
['-0.        1.00000000e+00']  # Fail
```

Please give me some advice.

Comment: You have to include the Python code with which you do the test cases, or explain how the fourth- and third-to-last test case result in `Fail`. Does `Fail` mean it matches while it shouldn't match, or it doesn't match while it should?

Comment: Are the apostrophes and/or square brackets part of the string to be matched?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(-?[01]\.(?:00000000e\+00| {1,8})?)\s(-?[01]\.(?:00000000e\+00| {1,8})?)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `-?[01]\.` Match an optional `-` either `0` or `1` and a `.` (note to escape the dot)
  - `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation `|`

    - `00000000e\+00| {1,8}` Match either `00000000e+00` or 1-8 spaces
  - `)?` Close non capture group and make it optional
- `)` Close group 1
- `\s` Match a single whitespace char
- `(-?[01]\.(?:00000000e\+00| {1,8})?)` Capture **group 2**, the same pattern as capture group 1

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hpN3nW/1)

Note that `\s` could also match a newline, and if you want the match only you [can omit](https://regex101.com/r/zrzvk1/1) the capture groups.

---

There is no language tagged, but if supported you might shorten the pattern recursing the first sub pattern as the pattern uses the same part twice.

```
(-?[01]\.(?:0{8}e\+00| {1,8})?)\s(?1)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/e6zkwP/1)

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
import re

l = ['0. 0.',
'0. 1.',
'1. 0.',
'1. 1.',
'-0. -0.',
'-0. 0.',
'0. -0.',
'1. -0.',
'1. -1.',
'-1. 1.',
'-1. -1.',
'-1.00000000e+00 0.',
'0. -1.       ',
'0. 0.       ',
'-0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00',
'-0.        1.00000000e+00']

for s in l:
    if re.match(r'-?[0|1]\.?(?:0{8}e\+00|\s{1,8})?\s-?[0|1]\.?(?:0{8}e\+00|\s{1,8})?$', s):
        print("match")
    else:
        print("no match")
```

Explanation of regex `-?[0|1]\.?(?:0{8}e\+00|\s{1,8})?`:

- `-?` matches a dash character of length 0 or 1
- `[0|1]\.?` matches `0` or `1` followed by an optional dot character
- `0{8}e\+00` matches a substring `00000000e+00`
- `\s{1,8}` matches whitespaces of length between 1 and 8
- `(?:0{8}e\+00|\s{1,8})?` matches either or none of two regexes above

Answer (score 2):

Apparently you have two false impressions.

- You seem to think of `[` `]` as a group construct while it denotes a character class.
- You seem to think you'd have to include the string delimiting quotes in the pattern.

Since one could interpret your question to the effect that you want to test for two numbers of -1, 0 or 1, and others already gave regex answers, here's a regex-free alternative for that problem:

```
test = ['0. 0.', '0. 1.', '1. 0.', '1. 1.', '-0. -0.', '-0. 0.', '0. -0.', '1. -0.',
'1. -1.', '-1. 1.', '-1. -1.', '-1.00000000e+00 0.', '0. -1.       ', '0. 0.       ',
'-0.00000000e+00 1.00000000e+00', '-0.        1.00000000e+00', 'x y', '-1 0 1']

for t in test:
    print([t], end='\t')
    s = t.split()
    try:
        if len(s) != 2: raise ValueError
        for f in s:
            g = float(f)
            if g!=-1 and g!=0 and g!=1: raise ValueError
    except ValueError:
        print('Fail')
    else:
        print('Pass')
```